# How to obtain the Lagrangian of the fractional classical mechanics

Tags: fractional-calculus

The Lagrangian of fractional classical mechanics $L_\alpha(\dot{q},q)$ is defined as
$$
L_\alpha(\dot{q}, q)=p\dot{q}-H_\alpha(p,q)
$$
where
$$
\begin{split}
p & =\frac{\partial L_\alpha(\dot{q}, q)}{\partial \dot{q}}, \\
H_\alpha(p, q)&=D_\alpha |p|^\alpha + V(q), \qquad 1 < \alpha \le 2
\end{split}
$$
How to obtain the following using above definitions?
$$
L_\alpha(\dot{q}, q)=\left(\frac{1}{\alpha D_\alpha}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha-1}} \frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}|\dot{q}|^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}}, \qquad 1 < \alpha \le 2
$$

**Source:** *Fractional Quantum Mechanics*, Nick Laskin, World Scientific, 2018, page 260, [MR3821542](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3821542), [Zbl 1425.81007](https://zbmath.org/1425.81007).

Comment: Apart from a missing $-V$, you can just verify this works by inserting the final expression for $L$ into the first three defining relations, no?

Comment: Yes, by placing the last relation in the previous three relations, I can confirm the authenticity of the relationship. But I want to compute the last relation from previous three relations.

Comment: Well, you're essentially solving the differential equation $L=xL' - (L')^{\alpha } $ for the function $L(x)$. So the first thing I would do is try a power ansatz $L=cx^b $ ... I don't think there's more to it than that.

Comment: I am looking for a mathematical proof.

Comment: Well, now you're changing what you're looking for. Then just go back to the start, verify the relationship holds, that's your proof.

Answer (score 1):

> How to obtain the following using above definitions?

Referring to [this note by Nick Laskin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0547.pdf):

1. Get $|p|$ from the first of Eqations (15);
2. Substitute this $|p|$ into Eq. (4) assuming $V(q)=0$ in the definition of $H(p,q)$ given by Eq.(2);
3. After trivial algebra we obtain Eq. (7), which is the equation in question.